# Generating triangle indices for marching cubes mesh

Tags: unity, c#

So I am making a programily generating cave program and I have all the vertices but I have no idea how to solve for the faces of my mesh. My code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class MapGen : MonoBehaviour
{
    Mesh mesh;

    int[] triangles;

    public int xSize = 20;
    public int zSize = 20;
    public int ySize = 20;
    [Range(0f, 4.5f)]
    public float SurfaceLevel = 3.5f;
    Vector3[] interest;
    Vector3 old = new Vector3(0, 0, 0);
    public bool ShowAlg = false;
    [Header("Slows down the scene veiw dramaticly when in play mode!")]
    public bool ShowVert = true;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        mesh = new Mesh();
        GetComponent<MeshFilter>().mesh = mesh;

        CreateShape();
        SolveFaces();
        UpdateMesh();
    }
    void CreateShape()
    {
        interest = new Vector3[(xSize + 1) * (zSize + 1) * (ySize + 1)];

        float seed = Random.Range(0.2f, 0.5f);
        Debug.Log(seed);

        for (int x = 0; x <= ySize; x++)
        {
            for (int i = 0, y = 0; y <= zSize; y++)
            {
                for (int z = 0; z <= xSize; z++)
                {
                    float ypn = (Mathf.PerlinNoise(x * seed, z * seed) * 2f);
                    float xpn = (Mathf.PerlinNoise(y * seed, z * seed) * 2f);
                    float zpn = (Mathf.PerlinNoise(x * seed, y * seed) * 2f);

                    if (ypn + xpn + zpn >= SurfaceLevel)
                    {
                        interest[i] = new Vector3(x, y, z);
                    }

                    i++;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    void SolveFaces()
    {
        triangles = new int[xSize * ySize * zSize * 9];

    }
    void UpdateMesh()
    {
        mesh.Clear();

        mesh.vertices = interest;
        mesh.triangles = triangles;


        mesh.RecalculateNormals();
        MeshCollider meshc = gameObject.AddComponent(typeof(MeshCollider)) as MeshCollider;
        meshc.sharedMesh = mesh;

    }
    private void OnDrawGizmos()
    {
        if (interest == null)
            return;
        for (int i = 0; i < interest.Length; i++)
        {
            if (ShowVert == true)
            {
                Gizmos.color = new Color (0.286f, 0.486f, 0.812f);
                Gizmos.DrawSphere(interest[i], 0.2f);
            }
            if(ShowAlg == true)
            {
                Gizmos.color = Color.green;
                Gizmos.DrawLine(old, interest[i]);
                old = interest[i];  
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This script is placed on a empty Game Object with a Mesh Filter, Renderer, and a collider.
Note they do nothing without the faces. 
I have set it up so the face array goes on the `triangles` variable and missing part of the script should go in the `SolveFaces()` function. Thanks in advance.

Comment: It would be easier to tell how you should assign vertices to triangles if you would tell us how the end-result is supposed to look. What exactly are you generating here?

Comment: I would like it to look like this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=M3iI2l0ltbE

Comment: First step would be to figure out which vertices are actually at the border between air and rock and get rid of all the remaining ones. Second step would be to create triangles from 3 neighboring vertices each.

Comment: `xSize * ySize * zSize * 9` is not the correct number of triangles. In fact, you don't know how many triangles there are, until after you do the algorithm.